# how can do slice and replace in python this str

Tags: string, typeerror

[how can Edit this string normally working same ways other str but not working here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBY0Z.jpg)

Comment: Please don't post code as a picture. Instead [post your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here on SO that other users can copy it. Also provide error messages with full traceback, expected output and real output.

Comment: thank you ı am new man in here ı did not next time I will do

Comment: Just edit your question, people acknowledge your efforts.

Comment: You might also want to have a look at tutorials. [There are functions for string manipulation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_strings.htm) to find and replace elements.